# Unable to establish session using blockchain-wallet-service

Tags: php, ubuntu, bitcoin, blockchain

I installed blockchain-wallet-service correctly and work well.

When i try to login on my wallet, or do any action, i receive this error message:

```
error: Unable to establish session
```

All works well, i started the blockchain service correctly:

```
blockchain-wallet-service start

info: blockchain.info wallet service v0.22.0 running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Waiting your answers.

Comment: any one encountred this error before ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error. It gets fixed by adding the **ApiCode** (at least at the first request for a walletId).

So the solution is request an ApiCode ([here](https://blockchain.info/es/api/api_create_code)) and always include it at your requests. Ex:

```
http://$IP:$PORT/merchant/$guid/balance?password=$main_password&api_code=$api_code
```

*- For me it also works an ApiCode requested for Payment v2 API*

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I have this error. I think it's of blockchain servers, I have many problem with it.
I've got this issue online, then i tried to change my Wallet ID and it's worked.